# Cannot connect to DB2 from command prompt on TLSv1.2 enabled port

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am trying to connect to DB2 version 11.x on linux from my local windows machine. Ran below command in by ibm's jre/bin, but still getting an error.

Command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)**>java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -url "jdbc:db2://serverip:50001/dbname:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=D:\path_to_certificate;" -user dbusername -password dbpassword
```

Error

> [jcc][10512][13714]Failed to create connection. SQLCODE: -4499
>   SQLSTATE: 08001 Message: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.25.13] A
>   communication error occurred during operations on the connection's
>   underlying socket, socket input stream, or socket output stream. Error
>   location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1). Message:
>   Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. ERRORCODE=-4499,
>   SQLSTATE=08001

Note - I have given `.cer` certificate file in certificate path (As in [this example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/249405/200411), `.arm` is given), will it matter?

What am I doing wrong?

Analysis 1 Ran below command on path, output is :

Command

```
java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version
```

Output

```
IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.25.13
```

That proves JCC version is correct (More than 4.1)

Analysis 2

Ran telnet from local windows machine towards DB2 linux machine on desired TLSv1.2 enabled port. It is success.

Comment: What port is your Db2 running on, and what port are you trying to connect to?

Comment: The URL you're connecting to seem incomplete.

Comment: @Lennart - Port is 50001 on which SSL is enabled by DBA team.

Comment: @mustaccio - Have copied whole URL. While posting it somehow removed few bits.

Comment: Still missing the database namee

Comment: And you can telnet to 50001 from the Windows machine?

Comment: After rereading your post, I think @mustaccio found the error. Try something like `"jdbc:db2://serverip:50001/yourdb:sslConnection=true;...`

Comment: @Lennart- Yes telnet is successful from windows machine to DB2 on port 50001

Comment: @mustaccio - database name is appended in URL, but error is same. Sorry for copying incomplete URL, somehow text between <> is getting ignored by site